# How to decide whether a food is non veg or veg?

Tags: food, non-vegetarian

As we all know that eating non veg is not acceptable. For our religion .when I ask this question everyone seems confused ,they told me that we should not eat by harassing other organisms ,so if we take veg as food we are still harassing other organisms, right? plants are also a living organisms right?

Comment: there is a degree of harm from least to max. the ideal way of eating is called 'uncha-vritthi' - collect grains, or fruits that are fallen on the ground, that way even the plants are not harmed. the worst way is of course, killing the animal (or plant) and eating its flesh. Now keep in mind, plants provide fruits or grains for food i.e. it is not the plant itself, but a part of it. Whereas animals don't provide their own flesh without pain.